# Why don't some Vuetify properties work in same component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm a newbie to Vue JS. I'm creating a sample Vue application as a part of studying. I use Vue CLI version and Vuetify. I installed Vuetify by following Vue documentation. I'm creating a template with the Vuetiy. Some Vuetify properties are not working. I've already spent a few hours on the problem but I still cannot find a solution. Here is my code.

```
<template>

    <v-row>

        <v-col
            cols="6"
            offset="3"
        >

            <v-card
                dark
            >

                <v-card-title
                    class="justify-center"
                >
                    Hello World!
                </v-card-title>

            </v-card>

        </v-col>

    </v-row>

</template>
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QeMo.png)

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W26uA.png)

Comment: It's working fine with [your code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuejs-vuetify-starter-fem1ra?file=index.html)

Comment: try to wrap around with `v-content and v-container`

Comment: @Naren I wrap with `v-app` and it does work. Thank you.

Comment: Did you see the example link?, It's working fine right